# Can't print any string using drawString() in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent, drawstring

I'm trying to find what is wrong with this short code. I can't print the String **TEXT** in my `JFrame` using `drawString()` method. Please Help . Only a plain white  screen will appear if you run the program .

Code:

```
     import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.*;

public class sample extends JFrame
{

    private JPanel panel;

    public sample()
    {
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        panel =new JPanel();

        Container mainP= getContentPane();
        mainP.add(panel);
        panel.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D eg = (Graphics2D)g;
        eg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        eg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        eg.drawString("TEXT", 40, 120);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new sample();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`JFrame` *has* no `paintComponent` method. So you aren't override *anything*, and not painting will be done.

On that note `JPanel` *does* have a `paintComponent` method, and you should be painting on a `JComponent` or `JPanel`, which *do* have the method.  You don't want to paint on top-level containers like `JFrame`. (if you really need to know though, the correct method to override is `paint` for `JFrame`).

That being said, you should also call `super.paintComponent` inside the `paintComponent` method so you don't break the paint chain and leave paint artifacts.

---

**Side Notes**

- As good practice, make use of the `@Override` annotation, so you know you are correctly overriding a method. You would've seen that `paintComponent` doesn't override one of `JFrame`s methods.
- `setVisible(true)` *after* add your components.
- `panel.setBounds(0,0,500,500);` will do absolutely nothing, since the `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`
- Follow Java naming convention and use capital letters for class names.
- Run Swing apps from the Event Dispatch Thread. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

---

FINAL

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Sample extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;

    public Sample() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D eg = (Graphics2D) g;
                eg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                eg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                eg.drawString("TEXT", 40, 120);
            }
        };

        Container mainP = getContentPane();
        mainP.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new Sample();
            }
        });  
    }
}
```

Comment: Spelling error on `paingComponent` in second paragraph. Wish I could +2 for good answer and then the extra advice given.